# ios - going from an integer (int or NSInteger) to an NSIndexPath* for a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview, nsindexpath

I'm trying to call `collectionView...scrollToItemAtIndexPath` to scroll my `UICollectionView` to the ith cell, where i is the index of the element.  My collection view has only one section, and when I go the other away around, I always call `dataArray[indexPath.item]` to get the data for the element at indexPath.  However, I'm having trouble getting an indexPath from an integer.

`[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:]` works only for `UITableView`

`[NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:]` doesn't return an `NSIndexPath` with a section

`[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:inSection:0]` returns a path of 0 length that, when used to get the cell with `[collectionView cellAtIndexPath:]` returns `nil`.

Any idea what I can do to get a valid index path that I can then use to scroll my `UICollectionView?`  Assume that I have only the `NSInteger` index of the data array. Thanks.

UPDATED WITH CODE:

```
NSIndexPath* pathToCell = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:curIndex inSection:0];
    CustomCollectionViewCell* updatedCell = (CustomCollectionViewCell*)[self collectionView:self.collection cellForItemAtIndexPath:pathToCell];
    selectedContent = updatedCell.cellContentView;

    // scroll to cell and recenter cover on it
    [self.collection scrollToItemAtIndexPath:pathToCell atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally animated:NO];
```

Then I use the location of the cell to recenter a "cover" view on top of it:

```
// Animate
CGPoint coverCenter = [childView convertPoint:selectedContent.center toView:parentView];

coverSelectDummy.center = coverCenter;
coverSelectDummy.imageView.image = selectedContent.imageView.image;
coverSelectDummy.imageLabel.text = selectedContent.imageLabel.text;
coverSelectDummy.alpha = 1.0;
coverSelectDummy.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
coverSelectDummy.hidden = NO;

[self.view bringSubviewToFront:coverSelectDummy];

[UIView transitionWithView:coverSelectDummy duration:0.1f options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^(void)
 {
     coverSelectDummy.alpha = 1.0;
     coverSelectDummy.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.2, 1.2);

 }
                completion:^(BOOL finished)
 {
     // .... processing ....
 }];
```

Comment: Can you show how you're using `[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:inSection:0]`? I'd like to see all relevant code to this question

Comment: Yes, shown above.  What's happening is that the IndexPath returned seems to exist, but it doesn't yield the cell that I passed in as an integer.  In fact, what I see is the cover view go to the upper-left corner of the collection view, not over any cell in particular, because the selectedContent is nil

Comment: Shouldn't that code be `[self.collection cellForItemAtIndexPath:pathToCell];` or am I confused?  It's unclear what `[self collectionView:]` even is.

Comment: I agree with trojanfoe - there's a mistake in your code - that's likely the error. Then follow the answer below and you're set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cellForItemAtIndexPath:` returns nil if the cell isn't visible ([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/cellForItemAtIndexPath:)). So if you want to scroll to an item that isn't currently on-screen, that won't work. If I understand correctly you just want to scroll somewhere, so I don't think you even need to worry about that method anyway.

You should be creating an NSIndexPath object using 
`indexPathForItem:inSection:`, and then scroll to that index path using the `scrollToItemAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:`

So, assuming the collection view is a property of the View Controller in question and you have a scroll position variable in play:

```
NSInteger itemToScrollTo = 10;
NSIndexPath *indexPathToScrollTo = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:itemToScrollTo inSection:0];
[self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:indexPathToScrollTo atScrollPosition:scrollPosition animated:YES];
```

Comment: That should be indexPathForItem:inSection: